# How to modify the node js request timeout in core set up or node js default library?

Tags: node.js, express, request, timeout, connect.js

In node js, Socket Timeout by default has been set for Two Minutes in the package itself which i found in the documentation. I want the location where this code is lying inside the package so that i can modify them.

I found the following alternate solution but I want it to be changed in the core library.

```
var serverInstance = http.createServer(app).listen(port, function(){
   // code 
}
serverInstance.timeout = 0;   // for disabling the timeout 

serverInstance.on('timeout', function(socket){
   // custom code 
});
```

For your Reference:
1.) Express.js is the server API
2.) connect.js is the session management API

Comment: where have you found that the socket's default timeout is 2 minutes? please give a reference for this

Comment: http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_server_settimeout_msecs_callback

Answer (score 1):

The socket timeout is set by calling [socket.setTimeout](http://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_socket_settimeout_timeout_callback). When a socket is assigned to a server, the server triggers a ['socket' event](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_event_socket).

So, you should be able to find out where the libraries you're using override the socket timeout. If they don't expose this as an option, you could override `Socket.prototype.setTimeout` to ensure that only the timeout you want is set.

Comment: Thank you Trevor Burham for your reply.